# Is there any optimization or different API for page aligned memory allocations on the heap?

Tags: c++, c++17, heap-memory, memory-alignment, memory-fragmentation

I am about to write a class representing a double-ended queue, just like `std::dequeue`, but with the capability to store any trivially destructible type, and without indexing support. Iteration or pop operations will only work knowing the types stored before. Most of the time it will be used as a queue/stack like storage, referenced by other types, as references are guaranteed to stay valid, even if it is pushed/popped to either end in between. Allocation and freeing of memory should be done in huge blocks. The systems page size seems to be a perfect fit for a default block size.

I assume, that page aligned allocation of the page sized memory chunks would make sense in order to reduce cache misses on iteration over the elements of the container. **Is this true?**

I'm afraid using `std::aligned_alloc()` with page alignment and size will lead to the heap's metadata (which for example is later required by `free()`, to know the size of the allocated memory) being stored in front of allocated memory, which would lead to a huge waste of memory (nearly one page for each allocated page). **Or is there any optimization or different API for page-aligned memory allocations of the heap?** For example, I could imagine an API allowing the client to specify where to store the required metadata, or which returns a pointer to the memory and a pointer to the metadata on allocation.

On the other hand, using the systems native APIs (Windows / Posix / FreeRTOS) to allocate pages would require a separate memory pool, which would be a heap optimized for page-aligned memory allocations. But having two heaps not knowing about each other could lead to memory waste too, as both will have a pool of preallocated pages. **Or do most standard library implementations free pages to the operating system as soon as they are not used by clients anymore?**

Comment: I forget to mention, that i assume, that page aligned allocation would make sense in order to reduce cache misses on iteration over the elements of the container. If this assumption is not true, using `malloc()` with its default alignment would do the trick as well.

Comment: `std::list` has the qualities you describe. You may like to give it a pool allocator for its nodes.

Comment: `being stored in front of allocated memory, which would lead to a huge waste of memory` On what is this assumption based on? You specified the requirement to allocate huge blocks of data with the size of block size. But you did not specify, do you need to allocate data _aligned_ to block size? `(Windows / Posix / FreeRTOS)` It's strange that FreeRTOS is there. What is the api to allocate "pages" in FreeRTOS?

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Using `std::list` requires each element to have the same type. But the purpose of the described container is to be able to store elements of different type. In fact, the container i am working on seems to be a kind of pool allocator.

Comment: @Frede You can store values of different types in `std::variant`, e.g. `std::list<variant<bool, int, double, std::string>>`.

Comment: @KamilCuk I forget to mention, that i assume, that page aligned allocation would make sense in order to reduce cache misses on iteration over the elements of the container. If this assumption is not true, using malloc() with its default alignment would do the trick as well.

Comment: @KamilCuk Using page aligned allocations: To my knowledge, the default implementation for small objects heap allocations is to store a small peace of data in front of it, containing metadata like the size of the allocation. Using this mechanism for allocations with page alignment and size as well, would result in the mentioned waste of memory, as after some aligned heap allocations and no deallocations, the free list of the heap would contain page aligned memory areas only.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin You are right, using `std::list<std::variant<t...>>` would be an option. But it delegates the same question to the implementation of the required pool allocator.

Comment: There are off-the-shelf pool allocators: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/pool/doc/html/header/boost/pool/pool_alloc_hpp.html

Comment: Page aligned allocated blocks are usually not very common, even within an application that uses them.  Using the OS allocation API will not lead to large memory losses.  In real-time applications, these chunks of memory are typically allocated once, when the application starts.  For an application, in a virtual address space, you shouldn't worry about memory frangmentation at a page size level.  And yes, freed memory pages are usually given back to the OS.

Answer (score 0):

For cache hit-and-miss optimization, page-aligned blocks will not help you much.  At that level, you should look for cache memory line alignment.  On x86 CPUs that will be 64 bytes.

Page alignment may help you in optimizing the amount of RAM being allocated from the operating system. That is dependent on the size of blocks your allocator will claim from new or malloc at a time.  Losses in that area are usually fairly small, or nil.  If using OS calls, compute the amount of wasted memory, using this formula:

```
(PAGE_SIZE - (BlockSize % PAGE_SIZE)) * BlockCount
```

For best cache optimization, align **individual** elements, including the list related pointers, on a cache line boundary, again, 64 bytes for x86.  This is where you will gain the most performance.  Beware! That is also where most of the waste in memory usually comes from.

The waste of memory in that area is

```
(LINE_SIZE - (ItemSize % LINE_SIZE)) * ItemCount
```